# how to check input box value contains dropdown selected string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created jquery auto-complete search box and i want to check when user inputs a value and if the search drop-down selected item contains that value or not. please advice.

Comment: A fiddle would be great to understand buddy!!

Comment: If I got you correctly then you are trying to implement editable dropdown with autocompletion ??

Comment: @shreya : im passing  two values as label item.value and item.category1. so my concern is if user type something matches to item.value , that value pass to input box when he select it from dropdown else item.category1 value should pass. for that only i need some advice

Answer (score 0):

Check out this basic example from jQuery's page:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks , but in my case im passe two values as label item.value and item.category1. so my concern is if user type something matches to item.value  , that value pass to input box when he select it from dropdown else item.category1 value should pass. for that only i need some advice . pls